# Как в Android Studio открывать вкладки с классами в отдельном окне?

Tags: android-studio

Не могу понять, как открыть вкладки в разных окнах. У меня несколько мониторов и очень хочется открыть вкладку в отдельном окне на другом мониторе, а не получается...
Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно разделить существующее окно через "Split vertical / Horizontal"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно также кликнуть и вытянуть вкладку файла текущего окна (на рабочий стол), таким образом файл будет открыт в отдельном окне. Но это не "живое" окно, у него не будет консоли, проводника и т.д.

Нажав на шестеренку любого модуля и открепив ("pinned") вкладки, их станет возможно перемещать как это окно.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось вытащить вкладку на другой монитор после разделения окна через Split.